# Did the most recent Mac OSX security update version 2016-001 (10.11.6) break java jnotify?

Tags: macos, software-update, java

I installed the security update 20016-001 for Mac OSx 10.11.6 this morning and now my use of sbt (0.13.8) with scala (2.11.8) and playframework (2.3.9) is giving the traceback below.  I'm guessing that the update includes new shared object files that are not working with the java versions I have installed.  I tried jdk 1.7.0_80 and 1.8.0_92.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnotify in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.macosx.JNotify_macosx.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.macosx.JNotifyAdapterMacOSX.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
        at net.contentobjects.jnotify.JNotify.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$JNotifyDelegate.ensureLoaded(PlayWatchService.scala:168)
        at play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$$anonfun$5.apply(PlayWatchService.scala:223)
        at play.runsupport.JNotifyPlayWatchService$$anonfun$5.apply(PlayWatchService.scala:179)
```

Update:

I ended up doing a massive clean/uninstall/reinstall of my java and scala tools as well as clearing my ~/.ivy2 cache. Something in there fixed it, but I didn't have the time to track down what it was.

Comment: By the way, my builds have slowed down significantly and this may be the cause.

Comment: It also happens with java version "1.8.0_102"

Comment: Hi, just fyi: I have the same problem. SBT dies every now and then with this stacktrace - and it is also very slow. Did you find any solution for your problem?

Comment: Did you (or @alwe) manage to solve this?

Comment: I ended up doing a massive clean/uninstall/reinstall of my java and scala tools as well as clearing my ~/.ivy2 cache.  Something in there fixed it, but I didn't have the time to track down what it was, sorry.

Comment: Updated to the most recent java version (8.0_111-b14) - did not fix the problem. sadface.png

Comment: Updated to most recent sbt version via brew (0.13.13) - did not fix the problem. verysadface.png

Comment: My best guess currently is, that while bulding the project in dev-mode the quota exceeds (no space left on device) and this is the reason for the exception.

Comment: It is possible that I did a disk cleanup at that time as well, but I don't recall it specifically.

Answer (score -1):

Delete ~/.ivy (it will be recreated) and run 'activator clean'.